# crontab and bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a problem getting crontab to fire two very tiny scripts for redmine.

This is a crontab (none root user):

```sh
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
MAILTO="hq@starfleet-command.co"

00 02 * * * /home/seven/issue_closer.sh
00 01 * * * /home/seven/issue_recurrence.sh
```

Now the two scripts, issue_closer:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Main script for exec the plugin issue closer

cd /home/seven/mars/ && bundle exec rake issuecloser:close_tasks RAILS_ENV=production
```

and the issue_recuring:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Main script for exec the plugin issue recurring 

cd /home/seven/mars/ && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake redmine:issue_recurring:renew_all
```

Now I will say that this was working on start, after few weeks just stoped.
The only thing that I can see o syslog is:

```sh
Jan 31 01:00:01 SC-GRID-003-003 CRON[45917]: (seven) CMD (/home/seven/issue_recurrence.sh)
```

Any ideas, suggestions?
Many Thanks

Comment: I'll note that the scripts `cd` into `/home/seven/mars/` and then run the issue_closer and issue_recurrence scripts presumable from there, whereas the crontab assumes the scripts are in `/home/seven/`.

Comment: I.o.w., what happens if you add mars/ to the two lines in the crontab?

Comment: Does your PATH usually have `/home/seven/` in it?

Comment: Or does your PATH usually have `/home/seven/mars` in it?

Comment: `echo $PATH` from the command-line should tell you.

Comment: The scrips are in /home/seven but the 'bundle exec' must be executed in /home/seven/mars that's why I made the cd before the actual execution of the command for redmine. I will move the script into /home/seven/mars and remove the 'cd', will see if it will help.

Comment: Output and errors are sent to hq@starfleet-command.co. Can you tell us what you received on this email address?

Comment: I receive nothing, no error. And the change in the script to remove the 'cd and path' plus movement of the script to the /home/seven/mars/ location didi not help :(

Answer (score 1):

when I run Crontab commands it is useful sometimes to declare the environment.

one was to run the ~/.profile for the newly created shell that the crontab will create when running the command.

here's my version that may help.

`*/15 * * * *  . ~/.profile; /.sh >> /log.txt 2>&1`

at least if setting environments doesn't help your program to run.

`log.txt 2>&1`

will send the crontab shell STDOUT & STDERR into this log file to show you any errors that may have been prompted back during/after it's execution.

Comment: and.... I just saw you already declared your env varibles above your scheduled cron task.... my bad